# Even when double variable, (45 / 10) outputs 4

Tags: c#

When I write (45/10) the program outputs 4.
Is this an error?

```
double newNum = (45 / 10); //output -> 4
```

Comment: Lookup "Integer division" for c#.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. 10/4 is division of two integers.
try it.

```
double newNum = (45 / 10.0);
```